# Dynamically created cascading dropdown lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, cascadingdropdown

This issue might be trivial for some but for the life of me, I cannot seem to figure it out.

Setup:
I have a dropdown (**DropDownList1**) added at design time.  **DropDownList1** dynamically creates other dropdowns (**DDL1, DDL2, DDL3**) at runtime based on the selected value.  The dropdown list items is generated every postback as default values.  Some of the dynamically created dropdowns (**DLL2, DDL3**) are also cascading dropdowns wherein **DDL3** data items are generated based on **DDL2** selected item. I have an **onSelectedIndexChanged** event on **DDL2** to generate data items for **DDL3**.

Problem:
**DDL1** and **DDL2** selected values are retained on postback, which makes sense since it is generated onpageload. **DDL3** shows the correct data items based on the **DDL2** selection, but upon selecting a value, the page posts back and loses the selected value.

Markup:

```
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upanel" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="container1">
                        <div id="params-container" class="container">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="input-fields" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="DatesPh" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="SeasonPh" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="CompanyPh" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="BrandPh" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="LocationPh" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="GenderPh" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="LinePh" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="SubLinePh" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show" OnClick="Button1_Click" class="input-button" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
//This is my design time dropdown.
//List item is generated only on first request.
//It has AutoPostBack=true so that new controls will be created based on the selection.

            DropDownList1.DataSource =  GetSqlData("sp_getReports",null);
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "ReportName";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ReportNum";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select a report", ""));
            DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }

//This is where I create all controls dynamically (some tb and some ddl).
//I am also generating the list items for the ddl here dynamically.  
//Everything happens on pageload.

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_fieldTableMap", con))
    {
        DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputRpt", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp.Fill(dtable);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dtable.Rows)
        {
            if (dr["SqlQuery"].ToString().Trim() == "")
            {
                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                tb.ID = dr["AspId"].ToString().Trim();
                tb.CssClass = "input-fields";
                tb.Attributes.Add("placeholder", dr["FieldName"].ToString().Trim());

                Control chkPh = FindControl(dr["Container"].ToString().Trim());
                if (chkPh is PlaceHolder)
                {
                    PlaceHolder pHolder = chkPh as PlaceHolder;
                    pHolder.Controls.Add(tb);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
                ddl.ID = dr["AspId"].ToString().Trim();
                ddl.CssClass = "input-fields";
                ddl.AutoPostBack = true;

//I am dynamically creating the selectedindexchanged event
//for one of my ddl to provide cascading dropdown functionality on another dropdown.
                        if (ddl.ID == "brandCode")
                        {    
                ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(brandCode_SelectedIndexChanged);
                        }
                        if (ddl.ID == "genderCode")
                        {
                            ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(genderCode_SelectedIndexChanged);
                        } 
                Control chkPh = FindControl(dr["Container"].ToString().Trim());
                if (chkPh is PlaceHolder)
                {
                    PlaceHolder pHolder = chkPh as PlaceHolder;
                    pHolder.Controls.Add(ddl);
                }

                using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
                {

//As I said, I generate the dropdown data items on pageload

                    DataTable sqlTab = new DataTable();
                    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(dr["SqlQuery"].ToString().Trim(), cn);
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    SqlDataAdapter sqlAdp = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
                    sqlAdp.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 60;
                    sqlAdp.Fill(sqlTab);
                    ddl.DataSource = sqlTab;

                    ddl.DataTextField = dr["DdlText"].ToString().Trim();
                    ddl.DataValueField = dr["DdlValue"].ToString().Trim();
                    ddl.DataBind();
                    ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));

//Chidambaram's modified code added after databind of "DDL3"

                    if (ddl.ID == "genderCode") { ddl.SelectedValue = ddlValue; }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
//End of pageload

public String ddlValue
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["ddlValue"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["ddlValue"] = String.Empty;
        }
        return ViewState["ddlValue"].ToString();
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["ddlValue"] = value;
    }
}


//Also added an event for "DDL3" selectedindex to assign its value to the viewstate

    protected void genderCode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control chkGender = FindControl("genderCode");
        if (chkGender is DropDownList)
        {
            DropDownList ddlGender = chkGender as DropDownList;
            if (ddlGender.SelectedValue == "-1")
            {

            }
            else
            {
                ddlValue = ddlGender.SelectedValue;
            }
        }
    }


protected void brandCode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

//Cascading Dropdown: This event generates the data item of one dropdown based on its selection.
//This runs successfully, gender dropdown only displays the appropriate items based on the brand dropdown.

    Control chkBrand = FindControl("brandCode");
    if (chkBrand is DropDownList)
    {
        DropDownList ddlBrand = chkBrand as DropDownList;
        if (ddlBrand.SelectedValue == "-1")
        {
        }
        else
        {
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@brandCode";
            param.Value = ddlBrand.SelectedValue;    
            Control chkGender = FindControl("genderCode");
            if (chkGender is DropDownList)
            {
                DropDownList ddlGender = chkGender as DropDownList;
                ddlGender.DataSource = GetSqlData("sp_getGender", param);
                ddlGender.DataBind();
                ddlGender.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));
                ddlGender.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

private DataSet GetSqlData(string SpName, SqlParameter SpParam)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SpName, con);
    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    if (SpParam != null)
    {
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(SpParam);
    }
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(DS);
    return DS;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Added some comments.

Comment: If you are postbacking on DDL3 selection, just save the selected DDL3 data in a viewstate and use the same  viewstate value to set to DDL3  in page load. if the value is empty the dont assign.

Comment: Make sure that any dynamic controls exist on page load or else the values will not be lost. I would guess you are losing the value because you are getting the wrong control. Instead of 'FindControl', use the 'sender' object which will be the dropdownlist control.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  @Chidambaram   I am using asp.net server controls and if I am not mistaken isn't that supporting viewstates internally already?  Just an observation, but my interpretation might be wrong on the viewstates.

Comment: @ATerry I am not sure what you mean by "sender" object.  Do you mind elaborating?  Thanks.

Comment: The event param 'sender' is the control that sent the event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the viewstate like below to set and get the value. once the value is utilized, then set it to empty or null.

```
 public String ddlValue
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["ddlValue"] == null)
            {
                ViewState["ddlValue"] = String.Empty;
            }
            return ViewState["ddlValue"].ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["ddlValue"] = value;
        }
    }

public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.ddlValue!=null)
    {
        //set the value here in ddl
        ddl3.selectedvalue=ddlValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance, but I am still lost on the concept of the stateless protocol of webpages.  Based on your suggestion and my understanding, I have added your ddlvalue function.  I called the ddlvalue from the selectedindexchanged of DDL3 and assigned its selectedvalue.  I then called ddlvalue again on pageload after databind of the controls.

Comment: Finally, I get an error "'genderCode' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items."  IF I comment the code after the databind then the code runs the same, ie., DDL3 generates properly but does not retain the value.

Comment: My question is, when do I use the viewstate and get the value of DDL3?  When I did a debug, DDL3.selectedvalue in the DDL3_selectedindexchanged event, it shows that DDL3 is "".  Is this because DDL2 recreates the data items of DDL3?

Comment: I didnt get the problem you are facing. Are you able to load ddl3 list values on choosing ddl2? and not able to retain the value of ddl3 on choosing ddl3? if so, then you can have the ddlvalue in above code as a global value and set the value on choosing the ddl3, so the value is reatined in the viewstate and set the value in page load.

Comment: If you are not able to load the ddl3 list item then my above answer dont work.

Comment: I can feel that we are very close now. :)  I am able to load values in DDL3 based on DDL2.  However, I am not able to retain the value of DDL3 on postback.  DDL3 always reverts to default value but items are still based on DDL2.  All my code happens on pageload so does it mean that DDL3 resets because I am reloading the items?

Comment: Yes, because of postback the values in ddl3 gets reset. In the above answer, keep the property like viewstate in public. Then, when you choose the value in ddl3, before postback, have a page event, in that event you can save the value in the above given viewstate property. so the value will be there until you make it null. so when the page loads after postback, you can check for the value in the property and assign it to ddl3. then make the property as null.